# How does one change the Keyboard Shortcut for the Intellisense Overload selector?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense

When typing an opening bracket on a C# method in Visual Studio the Intellisense appears for that method; if that method has overloads however, then the up and down arrow keys on the keyboard suddenly stop responding as normal and instead change the Intellisense displayed for the method.

This is annoying when you use the up and down arrow keys to navigate to the previous and next lines and then all-of-a-sudden they don't work!  I found that shift and up/down, in this context then behaves as up/down did but that in-turn means that shift + up/down can no longer be used to select to the line above or below.

Is there a way to change the shortcut for the selecting displayed overload in Intellisense so it doesn't override the normal Up/Down and Shift + Up/Down keyboard behaviour?

I've included a screenshot to show the problem.  Supposing the cursor is within the second `Select` which I have just opened the bracket of in order to see the Intellisense and I now decide I want to delete everything up to the open bracket of the first `Select` using Shift + Up then Delete.  I can no longer do this as Intellisense has now hijacked the use of my Up/Down keys!

[Intellisense Up/Down Key override problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/migh1.png)

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  Consider an add-in stealing the keystroke, do mention the VS version.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 although I have imported settings which I have been re-using since Visual Studio 2010.  I'm not using ReSharper, I think this is worth mentioning as I know ReSharper replaces Visual Studio's Intellisense with its own.